# Custom search incorrectly returns deleted questions

Tags: bug, search, deleted-questions

Using a custom search query results in deleted posts being incorrectly returned. I used the following:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[kali-linux]+closed:1
```

which is looking for closed questions having the [kali-linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kali-linux) tag, and it returned a couple of questions **deleted more than 6 months ago**.

[image]

The above screenshot shows that at least the 3 first results of the search were deleted questions, that should not have been returned (as they are not recently deleted questions of mine).

This is possibly similar to [Deleted answers showing up in search results; is this intended behavior?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173625/deleted-answers-showing-up-in-search-results-is-this-intended-behavior) on MSE, although that dates from 2013. I also found [Search brings up deleted questions in results](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5694/search-brings-up-deleted-questions-in-results) on Meta.Programmers. Is a bad shard at fault here also? If so, can it be nuked from existence?

Comment: Would we need to add `deleted:0` to the search term...?

Comment: @Braiam Tried that, returns no posts. Same as `deleted:1` or `deleted:waffle` for that matter. With all those combinations of `deleted:`, I have "Note: only content you own is returned when searching for deleted content".

Comment: Well, I tried your link and saw deleted post, so "only content you own" isn't true anymore... **anarchy**!

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Comment: @BhargavRao Deleted more than 2 months ago, that's some aggressive caching! :)

Comment: @Tunaki http://shouldiblamecaching.com/ ;)

Comment: I'm looking into this - could be that the elastic-search index didn't update the deleted status on these posts.

Comment: @Oded Great! I also noticed it when searching for [godaddy] questions, so it may not be limited to those [kali-linux] questions.

Comment: Yeah, unlikely to be isolated to one specific tag.

Comment: We are in the process of upgrading elastic - when the move is done, this issue will fix itself (with a reindex).

Comment: @Oded boo, no smoke screen test to check if the index works as intended :(

Comment: @Oded should be concerned that it happened with me while i was googling today , like searching this "find shortest path from parent to all nodes" showed me a link to deleted question i.e this one "algorithm - Printing all the possible shortest path between two nodes ."

Comment: @PavneetSingh - we are not in control of google. Many posts will be deleted after google indexes them and all that we can do is wait for them to reindex the page to find out it is deleted and remove it from their index.