# Search results contain entries that lead to Page Not Found

Tags: bug

Many entries on this search: [`closed:no answers:0 score:..-2 created:..2016-09-22`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=closed%3ano%20answers%3a0%20score%3a..-2%20created%3a..2016-09-22)

Produce a "Page Not Found."

Some examples:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39636941/in-jquery-how-to-give-min-date-for-datetimepicker
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39611155/google-anlytics-plugin
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39596140/i-have-tried-to-install-my-app-in-emulator-nexus-6-it-failed-with-error-insta

Comment: The questions are deleted so you can't see them under 10k of reputation, very probably the same bug as [this one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/335639/custom-search-incorrectly-returns-deleted-questions) which isn't resolved yet.