# Deleted questions showing up in search results

Tags: bug

I recently searched for unclosed [term](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/term) questions. The first question was the following:

[image]

However, it appears that this question was actually deleted:

[image]

Why did this continue to appear here? This question was deleted nearly 2 weeks ago, so it would be slightly odd if this was merely due to caching.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Custom search incorrectly returns deleted questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/335639/custom-search-incorrectly-returns-deleted-questions). Also see: [Some deleted posts show up in search results](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/400332/some-deleted-posts-show-up-in-search-results)

Comment: Also: [Community-deleted/Roomba'd questions are sometimes still showing/counting in the questions page for a given tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/416302/community-deleted-roombad-questions-are-sometimes-still-showing-counting-in-the)

Comment: @NickstandswithUkraine OTOH, the first dupe was supposed to have been fixed in 2016. I assume that this is a different instance of a related problem (that Elasticsearch index wasn't updated somehow).

Comment: So, I'm losing my mind - I just went to edit the new links into the dupe list, but I forgot that I don't wield Mjolnir in the "bug" tag :(

Comment: See [Some deleted posts show up in search results](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/400332), this happens from time to time. This example has been reindexed as I have re-deleted it.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Now, when I visit that tag, [it says that it found two questions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7c70F.png) (sometimes, a [different number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VybmI.png)), but doesn't list any.

Comment: @41686d6564standsw.Palestine: yup, and that'll take a while to clear. But clear it will.